# calculation in Mysql with specific conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned table:

```
ID    Var1      Date
A-1   5         2017-04-01 18:45:05
A-2   8         2017-04-01 18:45:05
A-3   5         2017-04-01 18:45:05
A-3   5         2017-04-02 18:45:05
A-4   8         2017-04-02 18:45:05
A-5   8         2017-04-02 18:45:05
A-6   8         2017-04-03 18:45:05
```

I want to calculate percentage of `ID` having `Var1` value as `8` on every day.
I have tried this but it couldn't work.

```
SELECT
  COUNT( ID) AS ID, 
  ((COUNT( Var1) / (COUNT( ID) )) * 100 ) AS percentage
FROM
  Table1 
WHERE Var1=8
GROUP BY
  Date(Date);
```

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. is not clear respect  which value the percentage should be calculated

Comment: @scaisEdge I just want to know percentage of `ID` getting created every day with `Var1` value as 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT Date(Date), SUM(Var1 = 8) AS ID, 
       AVG(Var1 = 8) * 100 AS percentage
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Date(Date);
```

This uses a MySQL shortcut that allows boolean values to be treated as numbers in a numeric context.

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (ID varchar(3),   Var1 int,     Dt datetime);
insert into t values
('A-1'  , 5     ,    '2017-04-01 18:45:05'),
('A-2'  , 8     ,    '2017-04-01 18:45:05'),
('A-3'  , 5     ,    '2017-04-01 18:45:05'),
('A-3'  , 5     ,    '2017-04-02 18:45:05'),
('A-4'  , 8     ,    '2017-04-02 18:45:05'),
('A-6'  , 8     ,    '2017-04-03 18:45:05');

select dt,count(id) NofID,
         sum(case when var1 = 8 then 1 else 0 end) nofeights,
         (sum(case when var1 = 8 then 1 else 0 end) / count(id)) * 100 eights
from t
group by dt;

+---------------------+-------+-----------+----------+
| dt                  | NofID | nofeights | eights   |
+---------------------+-------+-----------+----------+
| 2017-04-01 18:45:05 |     3 |         1 |  33.3333 |
| 2017-04-02 18:45:05 |     2 |         1 |  50.0000 |
| 2017-04-03 18:45:05 |     1 |         1 | 100.0000 |
+---------------------+-------+-----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: it's not daily but changing group by will solve that one too.